# MySQL create table with partition

Tags: mysql, create-table, partition

I want to create a table in MySQL where it has partition features. The following is my attempt:

```
-- CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tick_data
(
        stock_ticker               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,   tick_datetime              DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,   price                      DOUBLE NOT NULL
    ,   size                       INT NOT NULL
    ,   auto_inc                   BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)
PARTITION BY LIST(MONTH(tick_datetime)) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (1),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (2),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES IN (3),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES IN (4),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES IN (5),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES IN (6),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES IN (7),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES IN (8),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES IN (9),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES IN (10),
    PARTITION p10 VALUES IN (11),
    PARTITION p11 VALUES IN (12),
 );
```

Can anyone please tell me why there is a syntax error in creating the table using the above codes?

Comment: So waht is the error?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: remove the comma after `PARTITION p11 VALUES IN (12),`

Comment: Now it says "A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function". What I am trying to do here is to partition the table so that data from different months are in different partition. Any thoughts?